# A quick question about deadline extensions

Tags: application, graduate-admissions, funding, summer-school

I'm applying for several summer schools, workshops, and travel funds. I've also applied for a few fellowships. Almost all of these have extended their deadlines for application submission and/or supporting material submission. I've completed (or plan to complete) all of the applications before the original deadlines.

My questions are:

1. What are the typical reasons that deadlines are extended?
2. Do you think it'll increase my chances for admittance since I submitted my application before the original deadlines?

Answer (score 2):

Possible reasons for extensions:

- Not enough applications have been received
- The applications/applicants are not up to he expected standard (Almost the previous point in th esense that more applications is hoped to raise the standard)
- Something has happened in the bureaucracy that means an extension is necessary

Sending in an application to meet a deadline is always necessary and being early may set your application apart from the others but there is no guarantee. Having an impeccable application is a better bet on getting noticed than sending it in early. By impeccable, I mean well written, clear and concise, including all the necessary materials in neat order. But early is certainly not a negative but may not really show to the persons responsible for evaluating the applications.